# Template doesn't change when the model in controller does in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller which uses http service to load data in my scope object .
this works initially but when I change my model by user events it is not reflected in the template

Here is my controller

```
myApp.controller('statesController',['$scope','$http',function ($scope,$http){
  $http.get('data/states.json').success(function(data){

     $scope.states=data;

  });

  $scope.loadCities=function(state){

   $http.get('someURLforExternalWebService?path=/Cities?state='+state).success(function(data){
        var jsonData = $.xml2json(data); //the data I get back is in XML
        console.log('cities', jsonData);
        $scope.cities=jsonData.row;
         console.log('scope ',$scope);
      });
   $scope.states="lets change states";

  }

}]);
```

Here is my HTML (I have included the entire HTML file just in case)

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  //header includes

</head> 
<body>
    <div  id='test'>

        <select class="form-control" ng-controller="typeController" >
            <option ng-repeat="types in row" >{{types.type}}</option>

        </select>

        <div ng-controller="statesController" >
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="state" ng-options="state.abbreviation for state in states" ng-change="loadCities(state.abbreviation)"   ng-controller="statesController" >
            </select>

            {{states}}   //this is were I trying to test if it changes

            <select class="form-control" ng-model="city" ng-options="city.city for city in cities" >
            </select>
        </div>


    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

If you notice {{states}} remains the same even after the model changes i.e. after I trigger ng-change event. I confirm this by login-out the scope

I tried using $scope.$apply()  explicitly

But it  gives me  a error saying that digest is already in progress,

I understand that angular calls .$apply() implicitly when I use it's directives but in my case it doesn't reflect the changes in my model to my template.

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can't have ng-model on a div.

Comment: yes my bad I copy pasted and left it there, editing it

Comment: have states as a property of an object like obj.states. And do this for all other models too.

Comment: it does reference it first time and as it come directly under scope I don't need to use scope.states ,do I

Comment: Why do you have two `statesController`? One is declared in a `div`; another is declared in a `select`?

Comment: Just remove the `ng-controller` on the select. It should work. Have a look at my answer for details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in your code is that you defined `ng-controller` twice - once on the parent `div` container and again on the `select` element.

A new instance of controller is created for states dropdown using `ng-controller` which is different from the controller instance of parent `div` element.

When you're changing some value in the states dropdown control is going to this second instance of `statesController` on your select element and updates the cities on scope over there. But the `cities` element in your HTML template is actually bound to the controller from `div` container.

Just remove `ng-controller` on states dropdown and it will work.

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vLNxKR?editors=101) with that change :)

Comment: yes it did  work ,I been trying to get head around this for a while now, and just realize how stupid my approach was, thanks

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use primitives in you ng-model directive.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m